# Latest version Cordova + Xcode = Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cocoapods

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_GDTCCTConstructiOSClientInfo", referenced from:
      _GDTCCTConstructClientInfo in GoogleDataTransport(GDTCCTNanopbHelpers.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Everything was working fine before updating the Xcode version. I just updated to Xcode version 14.3 (14E222b) and all pods minimum deployment targets are set to 11.0. If pod version is below 11.0 then this error occurred.

I can try these step but still not resolve

1. Open Xcode
2. Click on your project
3. See the 'General' tab.
4. Remove Pods_myproject from Linked Frameworks and Libraries and Embedded Binaries

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? running into the same error

Comment: Same issue any update from anyone ?

Comment: ThinkBiz solution worked for me.. Only I have to manually delete the 'GoogleDataTransport' folder inside the Pods.. then 'pod update GoogleDataTransport'

Answer (score 3):

Update this particular pod
Like this:

- Open terminal cd - "project Location"
- Hit this "pod update GoogleDataTransport"
- Hit "pod install"

This work for me.

Comment: Hi it worked thanks, can you please update the answer as I have to manually delete the 'GoogleDataTransport' folder inside the Pods.. then 'pod update GoogleDataTransport'